# Hide Grid Cell on Phone Screen Size

Tags: material-design-lite

It seems like mdl-cell--0-col-phone would do the trick but no luck...  Anyone know the easiest way to hide/not display a `<div>`'s innerHTML when viewing on phone screen size?

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col mdl-cell--0-col-phone">2 (0 phone)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
mdl-cell--hide-desktop
mdl-cell--hide-tablet
mdl-cell--hide-phone
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: ah, could really use a link to where this info resides